# Add Message Inspector to WCF service in code rather that config file

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, service

I working through an example from Microsoft training kit (WCF). It entails adding Message Inspection to a service.

I have thus far create the inspection implementation class, message behavior class and a message behavior class extension.

Instead of adding the behavior through the config file I would like to add it in the service host file. Below are the implementation classes...

```
 public class MessageTrace : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        private Message TraceMessage(MessageBuffer buffer)
        {
            Message msg = buffer.CreateMessage();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Message content");
            sb.Append(msg.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            return buffer.CreateMessage();
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            request = TraceMessage(request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue));
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            reply = TraceMessage(reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue));
        }
    }

public class TraceMessageBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {}

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {}

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            MessageTrace inspector = new MessageTrace();
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {}
    }

 public class TraceMessageBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(TraceMessageBehavior); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new TraceMessageBehavior();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can implement using code only in following way.

1. Firstly Using an Attribute on your service class. Create a new Attribute Inheriting from IServiceBehavior.

   ```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class TraceServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
    {
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageTrace());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
    }
   ```

and then decorate your service class with this Attribute

```
[TraceServiceBehavior]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
     // Methods
}
```

2. Create the ServiceBehavior extending from IServiceBehavior, same code as above, removing the attribute only.

   ```
   public class TraceServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
   {

       public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
       {
       }

       public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
       {
           foreach (ChannelDispatcher cDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
           {
               foreach (EndpointDispatcher eDispatcher in cDispatcher.Endpoints)
               {
                   eDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MessageTrace());
               }
           }
       }

       public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

and then in ServiceHost, adding the Behavior programatically.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService1.Service1));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new WcfService1.TraceServiceBehavior());
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary to add the attributes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the endpoint behavior simply by using the following:

```
ServiceEndpoint endpoint;
endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISimpleService), httpBinding, "");
endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new TraceMessageBehavior());
```

So I have the extension and endpointBehavior defined in the app config, however the endpoint was define in the source file. Therefore I wanted to add the endpointBehavior in the source file as well.